# longtable captions in marginpar

Tags: captions, longtable, marginpar

I used `floatrow` to put all my captions (figure, table, listing) into the margin. The only captions left that i'm unable to put there belong to the `longtable` environment.

Is there a way to put the caption which currently resides ontop of longtable also into the margin?

See the example for a figure (with margincaption) and longtable (with caption ontop that i would also like to place in the margin).
[image: caption of longtable]

Code:

```
  \documentclass[8pt]{scrartcl}

  \usepackage[a4paper,
  text={380pt,500pt},
  marginparwidth=112pt,
  marginparsep=10pt,
  inner=0.8in,
  asymmetric]{geometry}
  \usepackage{floatrow}

  \usepackage{booktabs}
  \usepackage{longtable}


  \begin{document}


  %% CAPTION IN MARGIN
  \thisfloatsetup{%
  floatwidth=\linewidth,
  capposition=beside,
  capbesideposition={top,outside},
  capbesideframe=yes,
  capbesidewidth=\marginparwidth,
  capbesidesep=quad,
  floatrowsep=qquad}
  %% FIGURE
  \begin{figure}[h]
  \rule{4in}{0.5in}
  \caption{Test.}
  \end{figure}

  %% LONGTABLE
  \begin{longtable}{lll}
  \caption{Caption Table Test.Caption Table Test.Caption Table Test.Caption Table Test.Caption Table Test.} \\
  \toprule
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{time} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{triple} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{trip}  \\
  \midrule
  \endfirsthead
  %
  \caption[]{Further table data\emph{(continued)}} \\
  \toprule
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{time} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{triple} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{trip}  \\
  \midrule
  \endhead
  %
  \bottomrule \multicolumn{3}{r}{\emph{Continued on next page}} \\
  \endfoot
  \bottomrule
  \endlastfoot
  %
  0 & (1, 11, 13725) & (1, 12, 10980), (1, 13, 8235), (2, 2, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  2745 & (1, 12, 10980) & (1, 13, 8235), (2, 2, 0), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  5490 & (1, 12, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  8235 & (1, 12, 16470) & (1, 13, 13725), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  10980 & (1, 12, 16470) & (1, 13, 13725), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  13725 & (1, 12, 16470) & (1, 13, 13725), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  16470 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  19215 & (1, 12, 16470) & (1, 13, 13725), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  21960 & (1, 12, 16470) & (1, 13, 13725), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  24705 & (1, 12, 16470) & (1, 13, 13725), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  27450 & (1, 12, 16470) & (1, 13, 13725), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  30195 & (2, 2, 2745) & (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  32940 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  35685 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  38430 & (1, 13, 10980) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  41175 & (1, 12, 13725) & (1, 13, 10980), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  43920 & (1, 13, 10980) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  46665 & (2, 2, 2745) & (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  49410 & (2, 2, 2745) & (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  52155 & (1, 12, 16470) & (1, 13, 13725), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  54900 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  57645 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  60390 & (1, 12, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  63135 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  65880 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  68625 & (2, 2, 2745) & (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  71370 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  74115 & (1, 12, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  76860 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  79605 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  82350 & (1, 12, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  85095 & (1, 12, 13725) & (1, 13, 10980), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  87840 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  90585 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  93330 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  96075 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  98820 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  101565 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  104310 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  107055 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  109800 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  112545 & (1, 12, 16470) & (1, 13, 13725), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  115290 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  118035 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  120780 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  123525 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  126270 & (1, 12, 16470) & (1, 13, 13725), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  129015 & (2, 2, 2745) & (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  131760 & (2, 2, 2745) & (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  134505 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  137250 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  139995 & (2, 2, 2745) & (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  142740 & (2, 2, 2745) & (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  145485 & (1, 12, 16470) & (1, 13, 13725), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  148230 & (2, 2, 2745) & (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  150975 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  153720 & (1, 12, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  156465 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  159210 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  161955 & (1, 13, 16470) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  164700 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
  \end{longtable}


  \end{document}
```

Source: [Tabledata](http://users.sdsc.edu/~ssmallen/latex/longtable.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\makeatletter
\def\LT@makecaption#1#2#3{%
  \noalign{\smash{\hbox{\kern\textwidth\rlap{\kern\marginparsep
  \parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{\raggedright#1{#2: }#3}}}}}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Awesome, this helps me out alot! The table has a bit whitespace ontop making the caption top slightly misaligned. But putting a simple \vspace{Xcm} into the parbox allows to manually readjust that.

Comment: Is it possible to enable this for a two-sided layout with flipping odd/even pages? I know how to alter the line so that the caption would fit in the left margin but when i use `\checkoddpage`within the redefinition of `makecaption` using the `ìfoddpage` package i am getting a `Misplaced \noalign` error.

Comment: @bioslime you want the check to be inside the \noalign  so \noalign{ if odd page \smash{something} else \smash{something else}}