# Caption font size problem

Tags: fontsize, tufte

I'm using the `\documentclass{tufte-book}` and have a series of longtables for which I wish to place the caption in the margin.

I found a solution to redefine the caption for such tables in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/182653/caption-in-the-outer-margin-using-longtable-within-a-tufte-latex-document), which worked perfectly.

```
\makeatletter
\def\LT@makecaption#1#2#3{%
  \noalign{\smash{\hbox{\kern\textwidth\rlap{\kern\marginparsep
  \parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{%
\@tufte@caption@font \@tufte@caption@justification \noindent 
   #1{#2: }\ignorespaces #3}}}}}}
\makeatother
```

I'm also placing figures in the margin using the `marginfigure` but the font size for the captions of these are larger than the other text.  I read in the [Tufte Example Book](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CD0QFjAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftufte-latex.googlecode.com%2Ffiles%2Fsample-book-3.5.0.pdf&ei=ctSzU5ymLMzJPZfAgeAI&usg=AFQjCNHFhUvH_2uVNiRFy1eBK3s8uyJTjg&sig2=qAXtESQIAgUseqSFV8uk8g) that I can customise the style of margin content using (see pg31)...

```
\setsidenotefont{\footnotesize}
\setcaptionfont{\footnotesize}
\setmarginnotefont{\footnotesize}
\setcitationfont{\footnotesize}
```

...and these work, but they don't affect the size of fonts for `marginfigure` and there is no mention/description in the section on `marginfigure` (see pg23) of how to customise them either.  However they all appear to be the same size in the example document

I had a search around and found the recommendation [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86120/font-size-of-figure-caption-header) to use the `\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}` package/options, and this works, but it over-rides the custom caption defined for placing the caption of `longtable` in the margin, so its not really a viable option.

Can anyone advise as to how to modify the font size of captions in `marginfigure` or how to use the `caption` package but still define longtable captions to be placed in the margin?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could just replace \caption with you own code (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186615/how-can-i-arrange-multiple-figures-in-rows-of-3-in-a-two-column-document/186671#186671 )

Comment: Thanks, that is a really good idea and I will remember that trick it in the future, but I've simplified my situation in the description above.  Many of the `longtable` I am creating are automatically generated from the statistical package [R](http://www.r-project.org/) using the `xtable` package, hacking that to match my custom definition isn't practical for me at the moment.  I will however get a minimal working example posted next week (deadline looming this week).

Comment: Could you create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your problem. Something the community can use as a point of departure?

Comment: @Werner currently away on holiday will try knocking up a mwe when I'm back later this month.

Comment: @slackline: Did you think of using the `mcaption` package?

Answer (score 3):

Since \marginpar won't work inside a float, I used Tikzpagenodes.  It is easier to create separate replacements for figure and tables than combine the two.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{mwe}

% repacement caption
\newcommand{\figcaption}[1]% #1 = text
{\refstepcounter{figure}%
\addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\numberline {\arabic{figure}}{\ignorespaces #1}}%
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\coordinate (here) at (0,0);%
\path (here -| current page marginpar area.west) node[below right,inner sep=0pt]
{\parbox{\marginparwidth}%
{\raggedright\footnotesize Figure \arabic{figure}:\newline{}#1}};}%
\newline\vspace{-\baselineskip}}%

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\medskip
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[htp]
\figcaption{A very very very very long caption.}
\centering\includegraphics{example-image}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image: full page]

Comment: Thanks, that looks useful, although as with my above comment I really need to keep my definition to `\caption{}` rather than `\figcaption{}` or `\mylongtablecaption{}` because of how the tables are being generated.  If it weren't for that this would I think work well.